# how to echo cod39 value inside $pdf->cell() or store it in variable and print the result inside a table?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am trying to print a table in FPDF that has 4 columns, and many rows retrieved from MySQL.

Two of my columns shall print the value in barcode using `code39` in FPDF. The problem is that it's not allowing me to print `code39` results within the cells. I can do that only by adding the location to the `$i` and adding it to the location of the `code39`. Even though one page prints correctly, it then gets out of sync.

If you check on the output, you will see the problem I'm having.

```php
foreach ($result as $row) {
    
    $pdf->Code39(12,47+$i,'%'.$row['activity'].' START',1,10);
    $pdf->Code39(209,47+$i,'%'.$row['activity'].' END',1,10);
    
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],20,'',1,0,'c',false); // First column of row 1 
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],20,$row['activity'],1,0,'c',false); // Second column of row 1 
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],20,$row['a_description'],1,0,'c',false); // Third column of row 1 
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],20,'',1,1,'c',false); // Fourth column of row 1 
    $i=$i+20;    
}
```

**The output:**

[image: the output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing a cell that should contain a barcode, use the current cursor position in the document as the coordinates to draw the barcode

```
foreach ($result as $row) {    

    $pdf->Code39($pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), '%'.$row['activity'].' START',1,10);
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],20,'',1,0,'c',false); // First column of row 1 

    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],20,$row['activity'],1,0,'c',false); // Second column of row 1 
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],20,$row['a_description'],1,0,'c',false); // Third column of row 1 

    $pdf->Code39($pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), '%'.$row['activity'].' END',1,10);
    $pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],20,'',1,1,'c',false); // Fourth column of row 1 
}
```

I haven't tested this. You might have to add or subtract an offset on GetX and GetY so that it looks good.

Comment: Excellent, thank you... Actually it doesn't need any fixing, it worked right away :)

Comment: You should test it with an actual barcode scanner. Sometimes, barcode scanners can't recognize a barcode if it is too close to a cell border

Comment: I have printed the sheet, and tried the codes, scan okay.